# How can I more quickly get the interchangeable variables in a function?

Tags: performance-tuning, algebraic-manipulation

Let's say I have an expression like `a b + c d e`. This is equal to: `a b + c d e`, `a b + c e d`, `a b + d c e`, `a b + d e c`, `a b + e c d`, `a b + e d c`, `b a + c d e`, `b a + c e d`, `b a + d c e`, `b a + d e c`, `b a + e c d`, and `b a + e d c`

As you can see, swapping `a` and `b` will always result in an expression equal to the original expression and swapping `c`, `d`, and `e` will always result in an expression equal to the original expression.

---

The following code is too slow for more complicated expressions. Is there a speedier way to get Mathematica to give me all equivalence classes of swappable variables such that `f[a b + c d e] == {{a, b}, {c, d, e}}` for some `f`?

```mathematica
SwapVariables[expr_, variable1_, variable2_] := expr /. variable1 -> replacedInSwapVariablesFunction /. variable2 -> variable1 /. replacedInSwapVariablesFunction -> variable2;

VariablesIn[expr_] := Integrate`getAllVariables[{expr}, {}];

SwappableVariablesIn[expr_] := (
  vars = VariablesIn[expr];
  originalVars = vars;
  results = {};
  While[Length[vars] > 0, (
    var = First[vars];
    vars = Rest[vars];
    swappable = Map[TrueQ[ForAll[originalVars, SwapVariables[expr, var, #] == expr]] &, vars];
    results = Append[results, Prepend[Pick[vars, swappable], var]];
    vars = Pick[vars, swappable, False];
  )];
  results
);

SwappableVariablesIn[a b + c d e]

(* {{a,b},{c,d,e}} *)
```

A function which can be used for a complicated expression to test timing:

```mathematica
DetNByN[n_] := Det[Table[Table[Indexed[x, {i, j}], {j, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}]];

First[Timing[SwappableVariablesIn[DetNByN[6]]]]

(* 10.7118 *)
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Since `Times` is `Orderless`, all of the expressions are identical since the factors are put in canonical order. Consequently, `{a b+c d e, a b+c e d, a b+d c e, a b+d e c, a b+e c d, a b+e d c, b a+c d e, b a+c e d, b a+d c e, b a+d e c, b a+e c d, b a+e d c}//DeleteDuplicates` evaluates to just `{a b+c d e}`

Comment: how about `swapVariables[expr_, v1_, v2_] := expr /. {v1 -> v2, v2 -> v1};
swappableVariablesIn[expr_] := Gather[Variables[expr], expr === swapVariables[expr, ##] &]; swappableVariablesIn[a b + c d e]`?

Comment: @BobHanlon I'm not talking about Mathematica making them identical automatically, I'm talking about expressions that are mathematically equivalent when certain variables are interchanged. For example, symmetric polynomials are obviously not defined based on how Mathematica evaluates things, yet they have a notion of interchanging variables in their definitions. I'm trying to find out which variables in any mathematical expression can be interchanged to give an equivalent expression.

Comment: @kglr Thank you for `Gather` and `/.` with a list. They make for a much cleaner implementation. Unfortunately, I found that `Variables[a^b]` gives `{a^b}` instead of `{a, b}` and I avoided `===` because it will only find identical equivalences and might miss nonobvious equivalences.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex - to identify all variables in an expression, look at the bottom level, i.e., `Variables[Level[expr, {-1}]]`

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex I suggest you see [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) as your functions are leaking variables.

Answer (score 1):

Two functions that work with expressions that are `FullSimplify`ed as input:

```
ClearAll[swappableVariablesIn]
swappableVariablesIn[expr_] := Module[{vl = Variables[Level[expr, {-1}]], 
  foo = Module[{f = {#, #2} \[Function] Evaluate @ expr}, f[#, #2] === f[#2, #]] &}, 
  Gather[vl, foo]]

ClearAll[swappableVariablesIn2]
swappableVariablesIn2[expr_] := Module[{vars = Variables[Level[expr, {-1}]]},
  Gather[vars, (expr /. {#1 -> #2, #2 -> #1}) === expr &]]
```

where I use BobHanlon's suggestion in comments to get the variable list.

**Examples:**

```
swappableVariablesIn[a b c + d e ]
```

> ```
> {{a, b, c}, {d, e}}
> ```

```
swappableVariablesIn2[a b c + d e]
```

> ```
> {{a, b, c}, {d, e}}
> ```

```
swappableVariablesIn[a b c + d e + Exp[x + y z + b]]
```

> ```
> {{a, c}, {b}, {d, e}, {x}, {y, z}}
> ```

```
swappableVariablesIn2[a b c + d e + Exp[x + y z + b]]
```

> ```
> {{a, c}, {b}, {d, e}, {x}, {y, z}}
> ```

```
expr2 = FullSimplify[Sin[2 a] + 2 Sin[b] Cos[b]];

swappableVariablesIn[expr2]
```

> ```
> {{a, b}}
> ```

```
swappableVariablesIn2[expr2]
```

> ```
> {{a, b}}
> ```

These functions can only handle expressions without subscripted/indexed variables. So we use a modified version of OP's `DetNByN[6]` to compare timings of `swappableVariablesIn` versus `SwappableVariablesIn`:

```
expr3 = DetNByN[6] /. Indexed -> (Symbol["x" <> StringJoin @@ IntegerString[#2]] &);

expr3simplified = FullSimplify[expr3];

First @ AbsoluteTiming[res0 = swappableVariablesIn[expr3]]
```

> ```
> 0.307439
> ```

```
First @ AbsoluteTiming[res1 = swappableVariablesIn[expr3simplified]]
```

> ```
> 0.309724
> ```

```
First @ AbsoluteTiming[res2 = swappableVariablesIn2[expr3simplified]]
```

> ```
> 0.734264
> ```

Compare with  `SwappableVariablesIn` from Chai's self-answer:

```
First @ AbsoluteTiming[res3 = SwappableVariablesIn[expr3simplified]]
```

> ```
> 81.6676
> ```

```
First @ AbsoluteTiming[res4 = SwappableVariablesIn[expr3]]
```

> ```
> 154.641
> ```

```
 res0 == res1 == res2 == res3 == res4
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: I found an expression that this fails on: `Sin[2a] + 2 Sin[b] Cos[b]`. Since sin(2x) = 2 sin(x) cos(x), sin(2a) + 2 sin(b) cos(b) = 2 sin(a) cos(a) + sin(2b). I found that `TrueQ[FullSimplify[left == right]]` handles it, but it's much slower, unfortunately.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex, please see the updated version.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [Patterns Guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Patterns.html) with [`Attributes`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Attributes.html) and [`Orderless`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless.html) to identify functions whose parameters can be swapped.

```
ClearAll[swappableParams]
Options[swappableParams] = {Method -> "Verbose", Indexed -> False};
swappableParams[expr_, OptionsPattern[swappableParams]] :=
 Module[{pos, paramsets},
  pos = Position[
     h_[p__] /; ContainsAny[Attributes[h], {Orderless}]
       && Switch[
        OptionValue[Method]
        , "Verbose"
        , True
        , "Terse"
        , (Position[h1_[p1__] /; ContainsAny[Attributes[h1], {Orderless}]][{p}] == {})
        , _
        , 
        Confirm[$Failed, "Unknown Method", 
         swappableParams::MethodUnknown]
        ]
     ][expr];
  paramsets = Extract[expr, pos, Apply[List]];
  If[OptionValue[Indexed],
   Transpose@{pos, paramsets},
   paramsets
   ]
  ]
```

`swappableParams` returns the sets of parameters that can be swapped. The `Method` option controls whether top level expressions are included, `"Verbose"`, or only bottom level expressions, `"Terse`". use the `Indexed` option to return the index of the swappable set.

For example with

```
expr = a b c + d e + E^(b + x + y z)
```

Then

```
swappableParams[expr, Method -> "Terse"]
```

> ```
> {{a, b, c}, {d, e}, {y, z}}
> ```

and

```
swappableParams[expr, Method -> "Verbose", Indexed -> True]
```

> ```
> {
>  {{1}, {a, b, c}}, 
>  {{2}, {d, e}}, 
>  {{3, 2, 3}, {y, z}}, 
>  {{3, 2}, {b, x, y z}}, 
>  {{}, {a b c, d e, E^(b + x + y z)}}
> }
> ```

With speed comparison notice that `SwappableVariablesIn` from OP seems to fall over for `DetNByN` with `n >= 3`.

```
DetNByN[3]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

so we would expect 6 sets of parameters that can be swapped. However,

```
SwappableVariablesIn[DetNByN[3]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

With `swappableParams` the 6 sets are returned.

```
swappableParams[DetNByN[3], Method -> "Terse"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Nevertheless, `swappableParams` is much faster that `SwappableVariablesIn`

```
Timing[SwappableVariablesIn[DetNByN[6]];]
```

> ```
> {9.25, Null}
> ```

```
Timing[swappableParams[DetNByN[6], Method -> "Terse"];]
```

> ```
> {0.3125, Null}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @kglt's comment above, I was able to shrink down my code *considerably* as well as, I think, handle more equivalent statements than before while maintaining some speed thanks to @kglt's tip to use `===` for speed. Unfortunately, the extra accuracy comes at the cost of an even slower implementation.

My old code couldn't handle `SwappableVariablesIn[Sin[2a] + 2 Sin[b] Cos[b]]` because it couldn't see that $\sin(2a) + 2 \sin(b) \cos(b) = \sin(2b) + 2 \sin(a) \cos(a)$. Now, due to an initial `FullSimplify`, it can:

```mathematica
SwappableVariablesIn[expr_] := (
  vars = Integrate`getAllVariables[{expr}, {}];
  expr2 = FullSimplify[expr];
  Gather[vars, TrueQ[(expr2 /. {#1 -> #2, #2 -> #1}) === expr2] &]
);
```